# Update certain fields from API request architecture or design pattern with ASP.NET Web API

Tags: .net, api, post, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have an API that can update an entity that exists already. This entity can be manually updated through an interface also where the API exists.

My question is what is a good design pattern or architecture on how to update only certain fields the vendor may send via the API on the entity?  I don't want to override fields with NULL or empty strings just because they didn't know those values when sending to the API, but the entity in the database may already have a value for that field.

This should also take into account if a vendor WANTS to reset a field to an empty string of some sort.

**Entity API Model**

```
ID
Name
TwitterHandle
```

**Entity Database Model with Values**

```
ID = 200
Name = Hello
TwitterHandle = @hello
```

**Entity Request Model send to API with Values**

```
ID = 200
Name = Hello2
```

This request should only update the name to Hello2 but leave TwitterHandle alone.  However, in another request they can reset the TwitterHandle if something was sent with it (NULL, empty string)

Comment: I would recommend accepting a ViewModel or DTO that contains only the properties able to be edited for the specific call. This would mean that you would potentially have multiple. Don't send entities back and forth through your API.

Comment: I have 100 clients using this API so I’m not going to create a model for each one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I found a solution with Newtonsoft

```
JsonConvert.PopulateObject
```

[Populate Object](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PopulateObject.htm)

Comment: did u test it? as is it not working for me. i tried their sample with dynamic object but didn't notice any change to my oject after PopulateObject method

Comment: Yes I tested it?

Answer (score 1):

One thing we have done in the past is to create an endpoint "http://webapi.com/twitter/200/name" and then do a put containing the value for the update. It's not perfect but it gets the job done and is pretty easy to implement.

Comment: Getting closer, but they may want to update multiple properties.  I don’t want them to send a comma separated list either.  I’d rather send an object, verify in a generic way what fields are missing and only update the ones in the put request.

Comment: The only thing to do at that point really would be something similar to the patch, you could use a JsonObject but your mapping config is going to not be fun. Keep in mind that nulls are removed from json so there is no way to tell if they sent null or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it at API Level then you can use the HttpPatch as below

```
public void Patch(Guid id, JsonPatchDocument<SomeDto> patch) {
    // Perform validation
    var objectToUpdate = repo.GetById(id); // replace this with your database call
    patch.ApplyUpdatesTo(objectToUpdate); 
    repo.Save(objectToUpdate); // save it to database
}
```

Another approach I would take is to use Automapper. In that I will create dto object and automapper mapping class which will convert dto to database model. This way you will be following the single responsibility principle as well because your mapping will become responsibility of automapper configuration

Comment: Good suggestion.  The patch seems to have a bunch of extra stuff you have to send to do an update which I don’t want.  We already use automapper so we could do a mapping for this scenario but again what determines which properties should be updated.  I think the best option is to serialize the request manually and test if the property is available in the request then update the database model property which both properties must be exact.